# Remove whitespace or something from array php

Tags: php, arrays, whitespace

### Try to remove these whitespace array form this

Im also trying to remove whitespace with preg_replace, explode, trim

```
`Array
(
[0] => s
[1] => 
[2] => s
[3] => 
[4] => a
[5] => 
[6] => i
[7] => 
[8] => 2
[9] => 
[10] => 2
)`
```

Comment: Please show what you have tried.

Comment: $newmail=preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $email);

Comment: $charSet = preg_replace(array('/\s{2,}/', '/[\t\n]/'), ' ', $email);
            $charSet = rtrim($charSet);
            $charSetArray = explode(" ", $charSet);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `array_filter` to remove empty array elements

```
$arr = array('s','','s','','a','i','',2,'',2);

$arr = array_filter($arr);

echo "<pre>";
print_r( $arr );
echo "</pre>";
```

This will result to:

```
Array
(
    [0] => s
    [2] => s
    [4] => a
    [5] => i
    [7] => 2
    [9] => 2
)
```

---

Or you can use `trim` as callback if there are multiples spaces. Like:

```
$arr = array('s','   ','s','    ','a','i','   ',2,'',2);

$arr = array_filter($arr,'trim');

echo "<pre>";
print_r( $arr );
echo "</pre>";
```

Will get the same result.

Doc: [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php)